# Best way to send big file

Tags: java, file-upload

What is the best way to send big file?

I'm going to write modular system in Java or other JVM language, and one of my goals is a big files transmission (>100 Mb). I didn't decided which web server and technology I will use (I'm thinking on using built-in Jetty)

I've tried MTOM before, but got really undefined behavior on different OSes (it didn't work on Mac OS 10.7 and worked on Fedora 18). Can you advice the best and easiest-to-use file transmission method?

**EDIT:** I'm going to upload JAR-files

Comment: I'm going to upload JAR-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to do LARGE amounts of data is going to be with raw socket access.
You will hit the Out of Memory issues on large files with most other methods.
Socket handling is really pretty straight forward in Java, and it will let you stream the data without loading the entire file into memory

OR

You might want to have a look at [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), this is the library that google uses to exchange data. Its very efficient and extensible. On a sidenote, Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of 1TB harddisks!

Comment: If protobuf supports data streaming?